# Разрешить доступ к содержимому фрейма

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, .htaccess, iframe

Нужно сделать так, чтобы к содержимому моей страницы был доступ через iframe (с другого домена)

Код, который я использую (iplg.22web.org/frame.php):

```php
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
    header("X-Frame-Options: ALLOW_FROM *");
?>
<h1>test</h1>
```

И JS с другого домена (bclib.22web.org):

```js
let f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.src = 'http://iplg.22web.org/frame.php';
document.body.appendChild(f);
let doc = f.contentWindow.document;
```

И я либо получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://bclib.22web.org" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Либо нет, но контент страницы все равно недоступен:

```js
> doc.body.innerHTML
< ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контент страницы недоступен, потому что вы запрашиваете его до того, как он был загружен.
Можно сделать так:

```js
let f = document.createElement('iframe');

f.onload = function() {
    console.log(f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML)
}

f.src = 'http://iplg.22web.org/frame.php';
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

---

**UPD**
Насколько я понял, вы не можете обойти кросс-доменную политику, если страница в iframe с другого домена. Но если у вас есть доступ ко второму домену, то можно использовать [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) для обмена сообщениями:

```js
window.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

let f = document.createElement('iframe');

f.onload = function() {
    f.contentWindow.postMessage('getBody', '*');
}

f.src = 'http://some.domain/frame.php';
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

**frame.php**

```js
<h1>test</h1>
<script>
window.onmessage = function(event) {
    if(event.data == 'getBody') {
        event.source.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML, event.origin);
    }
};
</script>
```

---

**UPD2**
Обратил внимание, что ваши скрипты располагаются на поддоменах. В этом случае, есть решение проще:

```js
document.domain = "22web.org";

let f = document.createElement('iframe');

f.onload = function() {
    console.log(f.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
}

f.src = 'http://iplg.22web.org/frame.php';
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

**frame.php**

```js
<h1>test</h1>
<script>
document.domain = "22web.org";
</script>
```

Comment: Это не работает, появляется ошибка: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://bclib.22web.org" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at f.onload`. Мне кажется, дело в PHP

Comment: @Nikita Дело не в PHP, а в `Same-origin policy`. Дополнил ответ.